# Leaflet map with custom latitude & longitude values not rendering

Tags: javascript, express, leaflet, ejs

I am using the Where the ISS at API to get the current latitude and longitude values of the ISS. The serverside request appears as such:

```
app.get("/coordinates", async (req,res) =>{
    try{
    const result = await axios.get(API_URL);
    const latitude = result.data.latitude;
    const longitude = result.data.longitude;
    res.render("index.ejs", ({latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude}))
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send(error.message);
        
    }
})
```

On my EJS template I have the following line of code:

```
  <!-- leaflet css  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <p >ISS Latitude: <span id="data-latitude"><%= latitude %></span> </p>
    <p >ISS Longitude: <span id="data-longitude"> <%= longitude %></span></p>

    <!-- leaflet js  -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <!-- Your custom JavaScript file -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And my client side javascript looks like this:

```
const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
const latitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById("data-latitude").textContent);
const longitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById("data-longitude").textContent);

// Map initialization with predetermined coordinates
var map = L.map(mapElement).setView([latitude, longitude], 8);

// osm layer
var osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
});
osm.addTo(map);

// Marker at predetermined coordinates
var marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(map);
```

When I load the specific route on my localhost I get a piece of text saying "Copy Code" and the coordinates below. The coordinates come through just fine, however the map is refusing to render. I am new to leaflet so I don't know what the issue here is.

When I load the specific route on my localhost I get a piece of text saying "Copy Code" and the coordinates below. The coordinates come through just fine, however the map is refusing to render. I am new to leaflet so I don't know what the issue here is.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
```

ISS Latitude:  
    ISS Longitude:

```
<!-- leaflet js  -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<!-- Your custom JavaScript file -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```